# Why there are negatve numbers in the output?

Tags: java, fibonacci

The task is classical: calculate the number of rabbit pairs after 30 months, taking into account that each mature pare gives three young pair.
The code is next:

```
    int young = 1;
    int mature = 0;  
    for(int n=2; n<=31; n++)
    {
        int take_away=young;
        young=3*mature; 
        mature=mature+take_away;
        System.out.println("month:"+n+"\t"+"mature\t"+mature+"\t"+"young\t"+young+"\n");
        if(n==31)System.out.println(mature+take_away);
    }
```

### Here's the problem:

Initially everything is great:

month:2 mature  1       young   0

month:3 mature  1       young   3

month:4 mature  4       young   3

month:5 mature  7       young   12

Starting    from 28th month output looks like:

month:28        mature  1674257764      young   -2113786333

### where does the minus come from?

Comment: Change int to long. The range of int is getting exceeded.

Comment: We basically use 2s complement numbers now, when a number gets very big the binary reaches the most significant digit, that number looks exactly like a negative number and the computer treats it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `int` and new number is more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Do use `long` instead.